# Excel Data Table Repeating Results

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am working with a model that utilizes the Data Table functionality in Excel to process many scenarios and collect the output. However, I will occasionally find that the data table will repeat results for sequential scenarios, which would be impossible.

The data table is generated with the following VBA code:

```
Sheets("ProjSheet").Range(Range("DTAnchor").Offset(-1, -1),Range("DTAnchor").Offset(NumScns - 1, 1))
                   .Table ColumnInput:=Range("CurrScen")
```

The calculation mode is semiautomatic throughout the code, and the data table is updated using `Calculate`.

The erroneous output might look something like this:

```
Scn | Result
------------
1   | 341.5
2   | 0
3   | 861.4
4   | 861.4 <- Wrong!
5   | 861.4 <- Wrong!
6   | 10.5
7   | 64.9
...
```

The workbook is not small at ~22MB, and the data table typically takes a minute or so to churn through 1,000 scenarios.

I can verify the result of any particular scenario by running it individually, so we know that the results in this case should not be identical.

These models are typically saved with different model settings and run simultaneously in different instances of Excel. They are also generally run on remote computers where multiple users could log in, kick off some models, and then disconnect and leave them running in the background. These computers have 8 cores so they could run up to 8 models simultaneously. Sometimes, the models are opened and kicked off in different Excel instances using a macro that writes a VB Script which is then kicked off by a .bat file.

I've had difficulty replicating the error reliably. One theory I have is that when more Excel models are running than there are cores in the remote computer, Excel freezes up during the data table process and cannot always complete its calculation for some scenarios, and therefore it spits out the same results it currently has stored. I don't know enough about Excel's inner workings to decide if this makes sense, though.

Has anyone else come across data tables that repeat results before? If you know more about the mechanics of data tables, do you know what might cause this error and how to prevent it in the future?

Let me know if you need any more information about the error or things that I've tried to identify the cause. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. The first two sentences of the post summarize the issue.

Comment: One more question: let us suppose the value `861.4` is right for `Scn` `3` but wrong for `4` & `5` as shown in the question. Then what's the right value for `4` and `5` if u calculate it manually? Isn't it some value like `861.4001` and/or `861.3998` (think about precision ... )?

Comment: The results for scenario 4 and 5 in this example can be checked individually and it is not a precision error. These are example values - in reality the results are typically millions or tens of millions. The scenarios are so different that precision would not be an issue. Additionally, the error does not occur at the same place every time, so it isn't something about scenarios 4 and 5 that is wrong. The VBA is correct - it simply creates the data table and tells the workbook to calculate when necessary.